# Why the range of x axis is plotted from 0 to 600 in the following Python code using pyplot? Should it be expected from 0 to 2*np.pi?

Tags: python

Why the range of x axis is plotted from 0 to 600 in the following Python code using pyplot? Should it be expected from 0 to 2*np.pi?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create arrays of sine and cosine values
A = np.arange(0, 2 * np.pi, 0.01) # range:0 - 2pi，step length: 0.01
B = np.sin(A)

# Create a figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

# Plot the sine values on the y-axis
ax.plot(B, color='red', linewidth=3.0, linestyle='--', label="sin(x)")

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the solution:

```
ax.plot(A, B, color='red', linewidth=3.0, linestyle='--', label="sin(x)")
```